# Django form not validating and saving into db

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure how to save the form into the database.  I know the form is not valid because I tried do something else within that conditional.
This is my models. I have the same thing for multiple values in models.

```
from django.db import models
class Initial(models.Model):
    happy = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
    )
...
    interest = models.CharField(
        max_length = 2,
    )
```

This is my forms.  Again, similar code for different parts of the form which I don't think is the problem.

```
from django import forms
from .models import Initial
class initialForm(forms.ModelForm):
    happy = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label='You feel happy / content',
        widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        choices = emotion_choices,
    )
...
    interest = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=True,
        label='What creative outlet do you prefer?',
        choices=system_choices,
    )
    
    def clean_init_form(self):
        new_init_form = Initial.objects.create(
            happyAns = self.cleaned_data['happy'],
            sadAns = self.cleaned_data['sad'],
            tiredAns = self.cleaned_data['tired'],
            jitAns = self.cleaned_data['jittery'],
            scaleAns = self.cleaned_data['scale'],
            interAns = self.cleaned_data['interest'],
        )
        return new_init_form

    class Meta:
        model = Initial
        fields = "__all__"
```

This is my views:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import initialForm
from .models import Initial

def submitForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = initialForm(request.POST)

        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            happy = form.cleaned_data['happy']
            sad = form.cleaned_data['sad']
            tired = form.cleaned_data['tired']
            jittery = form.cleaned_data['jittery']
            scale = form.cleaned_data['scale']
            interest = form.cleaned_data['interest']

            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/exit')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = initialForm()

    return render(request, 'survey.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: What does `print(form.errors)` say?

Comment: Is that print(form.errors) supposed to print in the terminal when running the server?

Comment: yes, but it would be best if you use it in templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages